# ReactDOM.render does not re-render the 2nd element on the list

Tags: reactjs, render, react-dom

im having problem with ReactJS, i

on `index.js` i have:

```
ReactDOM.render([<App />, <Footer />], document.getElementById('root'));
```

the problem is that `Footer` needs to add an 80px padding from the bottom only on certain pages
so on the `render` method i do

```
<div>
    {isMobile && window.location.pathname.startsWith('/summary') &&
                <div style={{height: 80}}></div> } 
</div>
```

but it doesn't re-render when window.location.pathname changes,
i move around the web app and it doesn't change only when i hit F5 it renders correctly on that page.

i tried using events on `window` but they're aren't invoked as well...

```
window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
        console.log('xxxxxxx location changed!');
    })

   window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e){console.log('xxxxxx hash changed')});
   window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){console.log('xxxxxxx url changed')});
```

how i can make it re-render? or make `Footer` work as React component that can render ?

Comment: try updating these props with in life cycle method of <Footer/> component class. In case you are using hooks, try useEffect() to rerender the component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem!

Out of the box, React is configured to operate on a single page (see [Single Page Applications](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58)), which basically means it deletes what's shown on screen and renders new information when an update is required.

Naturally, simulating the routing behavior that's observable for non Single Page Apps is a little more difficult - check out [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/), which is a library created to tackle this exact issue.